# Create copy of list and remove element

Tags: python, list

I would like to write something like this

```
S = [ 0, 1, 2 ]
F = [ S.without(i) for i in range(0,len(S)) ]
print F
```

and Python putting out

[ [0,1], [0,2] ,[1,2] ]

and have not found something like this in the online reference. Can you help me?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `[[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]`?

Comment: do you have a better definition for `without`?  There is some confusion over what it is supposed to do.

Comment: any idea which is the fastest of the solution below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> S = [0, 1, 2]
>>> F = [S[0:i] + S[i+1:] for i in range(len(S))]
>>> print F
[[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]
>>>
```

If you don't need the elements to be in any order -- that is, if you can use sets -- and if you want to remove items by *value* rather than by *index*, then this is a more elegant solution:

```
>>> S = set(range(3))
>>> F = [S - set((i,)) for i in S]
>>> F
[set([1, 2]), set([0, 2]), set([0, 1])]
```

Comment: This is subtly different ... it outputs slices of the list around a particular index.  @bradley.ayers solution outputs the portion of the list that does not contain a particular value. Consider `S = [1, 1, 2, 2]`.  I'm not sure which the OP is asking for.

Comment: @D.Shawley, you're right! The name of the `without` method is ambiguous, isn't it?

Comment: I asked for clarification.  It looks like [Felix Kling has another interpretation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195381/create-copy-of-list-and-remove-element/6195445#6195445).

Comment: That's pretty much what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Python provides [**`itertools.combinations`**](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), which does exactly what you want:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = [0,1,2]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(s, len(s) - 1))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Even better, it returns a generator, so you can easily iterate over all combinations without using much memory.

Comment: This is certainly the way to go. Unless, of course, @Martin really needs a `list` of `list`s.

Comment: King, a good answer given the OP's example, but maybe the OP doesn't actually want all combinations? Maybe he really just wants to be able to slice while removing one element. But it's hard to tell, isn't it?

Comment: @senderle: Well, these are all combinations where always one element is left out, so exactly what the question *seems* to be about (at least for me). I agree, there is much room for interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

A nested list comprehension can do the job:

```
>>> S = [ 0, 1, 2 ]
>>> F = [[x for x in S if x != s] for s in S]
>>> print F
[[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]
```